# Raspberry Pi QEMU stuck on emergency mode

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, qemu, emulation

so I've been trying to boot up a raspberry pi using `qemu` but after I put `start.bat` in and let `qemu` work for a bit it says[image: Error]

It won't let me enter

My `start.bat` file has

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M \
versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 \
rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
-drive "file=2017-03-02-raspbian-jessie.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw"
```

as you can tell I'm using `kernel-qemu-4.4` and `2017-03-02-raspbian-jessie.img`
can someone please tell me how to boot upt the real system

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue caused by a variety of reasons. Have you tried:

1. Mounting the image (you'll need a linux VM) and making sure `/mnt/raspbian/etc/ld.so.preload` is empty?
2. Also making sure  `/mnt/raspbian/etc/fstab` file locations are set to `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` not `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p2`?
3. Make sure you umount after the above.
4. Try `-hda` instead of `-drive`? (I think they're interchangable-ish) - If not, try on linux instead of windows, I've got the above working on ubuntu linux with hda.

Further details on these steps at this tutorial: https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/